# DropDownListFor not selecting value from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to present a Dropdown with the opening hour of an office with a selected value (opening hour) coming from database but it's not selecting the value:

Model:

```
public class ScheduleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OpenHour { get; set; }
}
```

Dropdownlist with all the hours of the day:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ScheduleHoursDropDownList()
{
    List<SelectListItem> hours = new List<SelectListItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 23; i++)
    {
        hours.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.ToString("00"),
                Value = i.ToString("00")
            });
    }

    return hours;
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Schedule[i].OpenHour, Model.ScheduleHours)
```

I have the integer 9 in the database but it's not selected when I present the dropdown, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the integer 9 in the database but it's not selected when I present the dropdown, why?

Because `9` and `09` are 2 different strings. So make sure you have an exact match:

```
hours.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = i.ToString("00"),
    Value = i.ToString(),
});
```

Notice that for the `Value` property of the `SelectListItem` you should not be applying the `00` string format.

Also make sure that the controller action that is serving this view is effectively setting a value of `9` to the `Schedule[i].OpenHour` integer property on your view model.

---

UPDATE:

It might also be necessary to call the helper like this in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Schedule[i].OpenHour, 
    new SelectList(Model.ScheduleHours, "Value", "Text", Model.Schedule[i].OpenHour)
)
```

Comment: Hi thanks but I already tried this but it's still not working, I get <option value="9">09</option> in the select dropdown and 9 has the Schedule[i].OpenHour value but it get not selected :(

Comment: Try generating your dropdown like this in the view: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Schedule[i].OpenHour, new SelectList(Model.ScheduleHours, "Value", "Text", Model.Schedule[i].OpenHour))`.

Comment: Great! It's working! Thanks a lot Darin ;) please change your answer so I can set it has correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which ever value you want selected then add property `selected=true`

```
hours.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = i.ToString("00"),
    Value = i.ToString(),
    Selected = true
});
```

above value will be selected when run page.